# define method on built-in type in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, prototype

Problem for example: In general `null object` means additional class which handle cases when object not found etc. 
In Ruby you can also define method for `Nil` class. And I want realise something similiar in js.

That's what gives me hope `typeof(null) //=> object`, but in same time `null instanceof Object //=> false`. So defining method for `Object` gives me nothing.

So the final question: is there any hacks to define method on built-in types?

Comment: I agree with you, sometimes programmers are too serious (or not enough?). "Don't extend buit-in classes", "Eval is evil"... Annoying quotes, often used as sledgehammer arguments, but also often recited without thinking. That said, I wonder if you could create your own Nil object.

Comment: @wared Overall, I wanted to hear some old legacy hacks like `__proto__` or getters and setters. Now (when I understand futility of my question) `typeof(null) //=> object` seems like a joke of js developer. It's funny represent it like haskell `data object = null | Object a`

Comment: @wared well, I'd say that in this case, and in case of "eval is evil" there is a pretty sound, proven by many years, justification.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't.

That's really bad form and will lead to nasty, hard to find, bugs.

Or if you do - do it with **greatest of cares**.

Read here for more: http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/

Comment: Everything is so serious about the js. I just make little web pages and not impose my approaches.

Comment: Well, for us, those who are "so serious" about the JS, it's a matter of professionalism.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in javascript too.

I am not sure whether I understand your question.But here is my take on it.

```
alert(typeof(null));//gives you object.

MyObject=Object.create(null);
```

This means

1. MyObject doesn't *inherit* from anywhere
2. MyObject  has *no properties* at all.

Comment: May be this is right answer. For example `var x = myset.findByName("name");/*return null*/ x.getWidth() /*return 0 or other default value*/`. To formalise my question: you should execute `null.SomeMethod()`.

Comment: But it will be truthy.

Comment: Its good that you want to learn about this,but practically this wont be used much..

Comment: @Onaseriousnote It can be viewed from two sides. It would be great if you are going to write according to strict standards. At the same time, many people are unaware of the operator `delete` as not interested in the subtleties of language. Although yes maybe for nothing in language have introduced override built-in objects. And dynamic typing. And a prototype model.

Comment: by overriding you mean to manipulate already given functionality...?like for example to modify toString() at its core?